# How to this python code for max depth using DFS working here?

Tags: python, depth-first-search

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, left=None, right=None):
        self.val = val
        self.left = left
        self.right = right

def max_depth(root):
    return root and 1 + max(max_depth(root.left), max_depth(root.right)) or 0

if __name__ =="__main__":
    def build_tree(nodes):
        val = next(nodes)
        if not val or val == 'x': return 
        cur = Node(int(val))
        cur.left = build_tree(nodes)
        cur.right = build_tree(nodes)
        return cur
    root = build_tree(iter(input().split()))
    print(max_depth(root))
```

Here it's giving the correct answer. But i can't understand how the **max_depth** function working here. More specifically the 'and' and 'or' operation here.

Comment: What *do* you understand about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression:

```
root and 1 + max(max_depth(root.left), max_depth(root.right)) or 0
```

is equivalent to:

```
1 + max(max_depth(root.left), max_depth(root.right)) if root else 0
```

This is because `and` will return the first operand when it is falsy, and the second operand if the first is truthy. The `or` operand will return its first operand when it is truthy, and its second operand when the first is falsy.

You can also write it more verbose with separate `return` statements:

```
if root:
    return 1 + max(max_depth(root.left), max_depth(root.right))
else:
    return 0
```

Comment: This is definitely a much better answer. Nice :)

Answer (score 1):

The `and` is used to check if the root is not `None`. So it is like doing:

```py
0 if root is None else 1 + max(max_depth(root.left), max_depth(root.right))
```